# Can you splice a single object property in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wondering if it's possible to mutate a specific object property in an array of objects using the splice method.

For example

```
const array = [
    { name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'},
    { name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Pluto'}
]

array.splice(1, 1, /* Can I mutate [1].body without replacing the whole object? */)
```

Expected output would be:

```
{ name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'},
{ name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Jupiter'}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Using `splice` method, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with the array, index and property without splicing the array.

```js
const array = [{ name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'}, { name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Pluto'}];

array[1].body = 'Bye Mars!';

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    { name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'},
    { name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Pluto'}
]

array[1].body = "New Content"

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements. So you can never use splice to update objects in the array without removing it.

What you want to achieve can easily be done with

```js
const array = [
    { name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'},
    { name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Pluto'}
]

array[1].body = 'Bye Jupiter 1'

console.log(array)

array[1]['body'] = 'Bye Jupiter 2'

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do this.

```js
const array = [
    { name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'},
    { name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Pluto'}
];

array.splice(1, 1, {...array[1], body: 'Bye Jupiter'})

console.log(array)
```

Of course you can do it easy.

```js
const array = [
    { name: 'Object 1', body: 'Hello world'},
    { name: 'Object 2', body: 'Bye Pluto'}
]

array[1].body = 'Bye Jupiter';

console.log(array)
```